# Running and using Windows on a flash usb drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, flash, window

I want to be able to use Windows **completely** from a flash usb card without to install anything on my drive **at all** (or at least - very a little bit) because I've already have 2 Linux distributives installed in it and I don't want to create a new partition because I'll be using Windows rarely. I'm aware about Virtual Machines but  they are not what I'm looking for.

Your suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you use Windows LiveCD/DVD/USB?

Comment: Use Windows 8 Enterprise ability to create `Windows To Go` disks.  That is the quickest and simplest way.

Comment: @SEARAS, does it allow to install applications on usb?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried to install while booting from usb (maybe possible). But it's easy to install software BEFORE booting. Just copy program files to usb (but some programs will not work in this case).

Answer (score 2):

use 'NT 6.x fast installer to install windows directly to an usb flash drive.

download these files

- [NT6_FastInstaller](http://www.rmprepusb.com/documents/rmprepusb-beta-versions/NT6_Fast_Installer.zip?attredirects=0)
- download *imagex.exe, bcdboot.exe and bootsect.exe* from Windows AIK or request hotfix [KB2525084](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2525084&kbln=en-us)

**NOTE**: if possible use devices(Flash or HDD) with USB 3.0 or higher

**PROCEDURE**

1. format the flash/external HDD to NTFS and set the partition to active
2. create a new folder c:\nt6inst
3. extract the NT6_FastInstaller to folder c:\nt6inst
4. copy the files imagex.exe, bcdboot.exe and bootsect.exe  to c:\nt6inst
5. right click on c:\nt6inst\installer.cmd and choose run as administrator
6. You should now see a green window with some text. Hit Enter and the Enter again.[image: starting Installer.cmd]
7. Now find the Install.wim file on your Windows installation DVD (or mounted ISO volume) - double-click to select it[image: select install.wim]
8. You will now be presented with a list of different Editions - these were all within the Install.wim file that you selected, choose the one you want to install (remember that you will need an activation key which matches the version you choose, if you want to activate Windows).[image: selecting image to install]
9. Now you will be asked to select the target USB hard disk that you want to install Windows onto:

[image: selceting the target to install to HDD]
10. Now enter in the same USB drive letter again for the boot partition (use the same USB drive letter again):[image: Select boot device]

11. You will now be asked if the disk is a USB disk - answer Y.
    If however, you intend to disconnect the drive and put the drive inside another system (e.g. notebook) before you boot from it, then say No to this question.
12. Unless you have a Vista or Server 2k8 source DVD, you will be asked what drive letter you want Windows to use when it boots from the USB drive. Use the default by hitting Enter.

[image: select the letter for the installation partition]

13. You will now be presented with a final summary screen - hit Enter to start the installation and wait a while.[image: review all the options]
    Check this carefully before you hit Enter!
    Note that the Target Drive letters should be the same if your USB drive only has one partition.

[image: start install]
The windows will work as a normal installation on a hard-disk. you can install applications etc as you do on an installed windows.

source http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/win7onusb